# How to reorder tray icons?

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change the order of icons in the indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26114/is-it-possible-to-change-the-order-of-icons-in-the-indicator-applet)

Using 11.04 beta. I see that you can no longer right-click and unlock|move tray icons.

Is there a way to actually re-order these?