# Is there a program to change the order of the indicators?

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change the order of icons in the indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26114/is-it-possible-to-change-the-order-of-icons-in-the-indicator-applet)

I found a [way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26114/is-it-possible-to-change-the-order-of-icons-in-the-indicator-applet) to change the order of the indicators but since the file (1) is quite difficult to understand I 'd like to know if there is a program to do it.

Thanks in advance!

(1) /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile:

```
[Ordering Index Overrides]
nm-applet=1
gnome-power-manager=2
ibus=3
gst-keyboard-xkb=4
gsd-keyboard-xkb=5
```