# How to move one button from the left corner of the top bar on Ubuntu?

Tags: indicator, button

I'm trying discover the name of that button that is on the left corner of the top bar on Ubuntu. It has these items: "About this computer" and "Users session".

What is the name of this button?

I want to move it to the left corner of the bar.

Comment: You mean the gear-shaped icon on the **right** side of the top bar? It's called the **Session Indicator** and I'm pretty sure you can't move it.

Answer (score 0):

That one is not a button, but is an icon, an indicator and is called **Session Menu**. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19166/147044) for the right Unity's terminology.

Now, I don't think that you have any chance to move the **Session Menu** indicator which is probably hardcoded by design, but you can give a try to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343886/147044) to see how you can change the indicators order.